# Join information from one table to another without joining twice cross apply T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have two tables. #t1 has logins and emails. #t2 has country associated to each emails.
I would like to join the information from #t2 to #t1 without having to join it twice. Joining it only once either in the inner or outer query would  break the `cross apply` logic.
My current query uses a cross apply to get rolling information as such (fiddle data below):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(logins AS DATE) AS Dates,
    count(distinct d.email) AS DAU,
    count(distinct m.MAU) AS MAU
FROM #t1 d
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT CAST(m.logins as date) as dates, m.email AS MAU
            FROM #t1 m
            WHERE m.logins BETWEEN d.logins and DATEADD(dd, 30, d.logins) 
            ) m
group by CAST(logins as date)
```

The only way i found to join the two tables without having to break my cross apply was to `inner join` it in both the outer and inner query which is probably wrong but at least the output is correct. I do that so i can add my second condition in my where statement in the inner query. when i apply the logic to my actual table, the performance is dreadful(fiddle data below):

```
SELECT distinct CASt(logins AS DATE) AS Dates,
    #t2.country,
    count(distinct d.email) AS DAU,
    count(distinct m.MAU) AS MAU
FROM #t1 d
inner join #t2 on d.email=#t2.email 
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT cast(m.logins as date) as dates, m.email AS MAU, country.country AS country
            FROM #t1 m
            inner join #t2 country on m.email=country.email         
            WHERE m.logins BETWEEN d.logins and DATEADD(dd, 30, d.logins)  
            and #t2.country = country.country
            ) m
group by cast(logins as date), #t2.country


+-------------+---------+-----+-----+
|    Dates    | country | DAU | MAU |
+-------------+---------+-----+-----+
|  2019-04-01 | france  |   1 |   2 |
|  2019-04-02 | france  |   1 |   2 |
|  2019-04-03 | france  |   1 |   2 |
|  2019-04-10 | france  |   1 |   1 |
|  2019-04-03 | italie  |   2 |   2 |
+-------------+---------+-----+-----+
```

**Objective:**

How can i find a way to join information from one table to another without having to join it twice. (fiddle data below)

The result should look like this (output from the second query above):

- DAU: how many distinct logins per country happened on day 'x'
- MAU: how many distinct logins per country happened between day 'x'
  and 30 days after.

**Fiddle:**

```
create table #t1 (email varchar(max), logins datetime)
insert into #t1 values 
('aa@gmail.com', '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000'),
('aa@gmail.com', '2019-04-02 00:00:00.000'), 
('aa@gmail.com', '2019-04-03 00:00:00.000'), 
('zz@gmail.com', '2019-04-10 00:00:00.000'), 

('cc@gmail.com', '2019-04-03 00:00:00.000'), 
('dd@gmail.com', '2019-04-03 00:00:00.000'), 
('dd@gmail.com', '2019-04-03 00:00:00.000')  

create table #t2 (country varchar(max), email varchar(max))
insert into #t2 values 
('france', 'aa@gmail.com'),
('france', 'zz@gmail.com'),
('italie', 'cc@gmail.com'),
('italie', 'dd@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Please explain what you want the overall query to do.  What is the `cross apply` doing?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query should ouput the daily login per day and the monthly login on a specific day (distinct emails for both metric). the cross apply looks at each login per day and sees if theres any login happening from that day and 30 days later which is how i compute the MAU

Comment: Why do you not want to "join it twice"?  Are you having performance issues?

Comment: @iamdave because i can't join it once as emails and logins wont be grouped with countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

So I had initially said the second should peform better, but I'll eat those words. The first works better by far in my testing.

In my test environment I generated your tables as permanent tables and first populated #t2 (I called it emailLocation) with 100,000 unique email addresses spread across 206 countries. The second table (loginRecord) was populated with 2,000,000 random entries spread across 1/1/2018 - 12/31/2019. Both of these tables are indexed.

The below query is basically the one I said would be slower (it isn't). The major difference in this one is that I am filtering the dates within the CTE to reduce the data set. In my environment this runs in 20 seconds and returns 48,410 rows. I didn't test how long it would take to return the whole set, but trying this same CTE with a self-join ran for 10 minutes before I killed it.

```
WITH joined AS
(
    SELECT
        t1.logins AS dates,
        t1.email,
        t2.country
        FROM loginRecord t1
        JOIN dbo.emailLocation t2 ON t2.email = t1.email
        WHERE t1.logins > GETDATE()
)
SELECT 
    dates,
    country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) AS DAU,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) FROM joined WHERE country = j.country AND dates BETWEEN j.dates AND DATEADD(DAY,30,j.dates)) AS MAU
FROM joined j
GROUP BY j.dates, j.country
ORDER BY country, dates
```

---original answer

It feels like you're stuck on using the `cross apply` logic.
Here are two options that don't use `cross apply`. Both use a CTE to get a nice clean grouping of your temp tables, then the first option is a correlated subquery (blech) and the second is a self join.

Rextester here: https://rextester.com/AVJS76389

```
WITH joined AS
(
    SELECT 
        t1.logins AS dates,
        t1.email,
        t2.country
        FROM #t1 t1
        JOIN #t2 t2 ON t2.email = t1.email
)
SELECT 
    dates,
    country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) AS DAU,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) FROM joined WHERE country = j.country AND dates BETWEEN j.dates AND DATEADD(DAY,30,j.dates)) AS MAU
FROM joined j
GROUP BY j.dates, j.country;



WITH joined AS
(
    SELECT 
        t1.logins AS dates,
        t1.email,
        t2.country
        FROM #t1 t1
        JOIN #t2 t2 ON t2.email = t1.email
)
SELECT 
    j1.dates,
    j1.country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(j1.email)) AS DAU,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(j2.email)) AS MAU
FROM joined j1
JOIN joined j2
    ON j1.country = j2.country
    AND j2.dates BETWEEN j1.dates AND DATEADD(DAY,30,j1.dates)
GROUP BY j1.dates, j1.country
```

Comment: i know it worked but damn my query has been running for over 40mns and its still not working.

Comment: I've updated my answer because I was wrong. See if the update helps at all.

Comment: i'll try that now. the other queries didnt work at all yesterday. hopefully this works!! shouldn't you put a distinct in the cte ?

Comment: Within the CTE itself we're not doing any sort of aggregation, we're just using it to identify which country is associated with each login record. Reducing the data set in the CTE is going to be the most helpful thing - for example, returning all the data in my sample data set for a single country takes about a second.